# Rotot hardware - batteries considerations

Tags: motor, raspberry-pi, battery, hardware, cpu

[please dont downvote, just let me know what infos are missing]

I built my **second robot** and I always end up with the **same issue** ...

**The CPU board always resets when a high rush of current is demanded by the motors** from time to time.

I use one battery to feed:

- a Raspberry PI 4 (had the issue with an Odroid board)
- 9V/12V motors
- RPI usb devices (webcams, audio , lidar...)
- arduino micro + pololu mc33926 H bridge

**how can I avoid this CPU reset** ?

- adding a capacitor on the CPU board side or something ?
- adding a secondary battery ? which means more weight (my LiIon is 200g, I now use a power bank, it's 400g)
- splitting USB connected devices power to avoid the PI providing 5V to peripherals ?
- something else I have'nt thought about ?

The powerbank has multiple outputs, not clear if they can be used simultaneously ?

thanks for your inputs

---

setup:

I use 3 x 2577 buck dc-dc to power

- RPI with 5.1V 3A
- 5V for gen purpose power
- 9V for 2xlego PF XL motors

power supply:

- Romoss Sense 6PS Pro 20000 mAh Power Bank, PD 30W
- Aideepen Type-C USB-C PD2.0 PD3.0 duper to get 5V/5A (in theory)

https://www.reichelt.com/be/nl/ontwikkelaarsboards-spanningsomvormer-dc-dc-lm2577-debo-dcdc-up-1-p282581.html

https://www.amazon.com.be/dp/B08FD6381L?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details

https://www.amazon.com.be/dp/B0B4JCCG9V?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details

Comment: You will have more success asking this question on the electronics' StackExchange forum.

Comment: since when robotics are only about software ? but thanks for the tip

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/688398/rotot-hardware-batteries-considerations